# How to add and update array in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a multidimensionnal array.

```
var ingredients_list = [];

var data_to_push = [1,50,'test']
ingredients_list.push(data_to_push);

var data_to_push = [2,'','']
ingredients_list.push(data_to_push);
```

Which give me the following array :

```
(2) [Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) ["1", 50, "test"]
1: (3) ["2", "", ""]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How can I update the second array and to get the follwoing output by finding the id `2` :

```
(2) [Array(3), Array(3)]
    0: (3) ["1", 50, "test"]
    1: (3) ["2", 35, "Updated"]
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: The output does not correspond with your code. Your code has numbers 1 and 2, and the output shows strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the item using `find` in the top level array and then use normal indexes to adjust the subarray:

```
let item = ingredients_list.find(item => item[0] == 2);
item[1] = 35
item[2] = "Updated";
```

Comment: But how can I find it by key `2` ?

Comment: What is your key field? The first element in the subarray? And do you mean `"2"` instead of `2`?

Comment: Yes the first element in the array

Comment: Updated answer.